# ServiceStack - DateHandler Nullable DateTimes?

Tags: servicestack

Does anybody know how to get the DateHandler to work on a nullable datetime datatype?

Regular DateTime datatypes get serialized properly, but DateTime? do not - is there somewhere I can tweak this?

Thanks.

ServiceStack v4.0

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;
```

On regular DateTime:
"DateUpdate":"2014-07-01T21:57:51.7030000Z"

On DateTime?:
"DateStart":"2014-05-01T00:00:00.0000000-07:00",
"DateReturnEst":"2015-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-08:00"